# Pop-up windows remove the focus from the actual window in wine / bottles

Tags: wine

I use wine / bottles to use a program under Linux that is only available for Windows. Actually, everything works wonderfully, I just have one little thing that makes working with it a bit cumbersome. The program occasionally displays help pop-ups when you hover the mouse over something. As soon as the pop-up appears, the focus is taken away from the actual window and placed on the pop-up, so that keystrokes are no longer entered in the correct window.

Is there a general way in wine / bottles to avoid putting the focus on pop-ups?